# How to get whole start week and end week by the use of specific dates using Carbon and Eloquent in laravel framework?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I want to get whole week by the use of the specific dates.
For Example i have single date of february 3, 2021 Wednesday. Now i want to fetch the start of week and end week using Eloquent and Carbon so the output will be like this.

February 1, 2021 - Monday
February 2, 2021 - Tuesday
February 3, 2021 - Wednesday - This is my example of date
February 4, 2021 - Thursday
February 5, 2021 - Friday
February 6, 2021 - Saturday
February 7, 2021 - Sunday

Comment: start of week is saturday?

Comment: I can't see that this has anything to do with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the example date in `$date`. You can try this code below

```
$now = Carbon::parse($date);
$weekStartDate = $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$weekEndDate = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

See https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this on your query :

```
$query = "2021-02-03"
$date = Carbon::parse($query);
$startWeek = $date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$endWeek = $date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');

$q = User::where('date', '>=', $startWeek)
      ->where('date', '<=', $endWeek)
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = CarbonImmutable::parse('2021-02-03');

foreach ($date->startOfWeek()->daysUntil($date->endOfWeek()) as $day) {
  echo $day->format('F j, Y - l') . "\n";
}
```

Produces your exact expected output:

```
February 1, 2021 - Monday
February 2, 2021 - Tuesday
February 3, 2021 - Wednesday
February 4, 2021 - Thursday
February 5, 2021 - Friday
February 6, 2021 - Saturday
February 7, 2021 - Sunday
```